# Wpf Extended Toolkit: DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetimepicker

I'm trying to format the string to look like this:

**17-Jan-14 08:00:00 PM**

This is what I have so far, how can I make the month portion to be alphabetical vs numeric

Code:

```
<wpfTool:DateTimePicker
                        Name="DTP_from_TAtab" 
                        Format="Custom" 
                        FormatString="dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss tt"
                        TimeFormat="Custom"
                        TimeFormatString="hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `MMM` instead of `MM`

```
FormatString="dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt"
```